# Calculating two weeks forward form a day, using a marker day

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to code the date of the Thursday which falls two weeks after a given date. It is more complex than just adding 14 days to a given date.

This is because if the first Wednesday after a given date week is the start date, two weeks after it, counting by Thursdays, is more then 14 days where the Thursday of week in which the date was declared is skipped.

I am thinking that it should be a JavaScript function that uses

// variable will hold the current date
var today = new Date();

// variable will hold the number of the day (e.g. Wednesday = 3).
var thisDay = today.getDay();

and then I will place it into the "thisDate" variable in an if statement.

Just to be clear, I am trying to use this code in a manner where the starting date is a variable which is given. I then calculate the 2 weeks after, skipping the week which the date was declared.

Comment: Any test cases? And what have you tried?

Comment: Does the time of day matter? like 1:15pm

Comment: you may try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: So in this case we have 7 weekdays. Say for instance Thursday is the 4th day of the week. You will need a conditional statement. If today's day is less than Thursday then the answer will be ((thursday_day - todays_day) + 14). If today's day is greater than Thursday then the answer will be ((todays_day - thursday_day) + 14). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) you can do it this way:

```
moment().add(2, 'weeks').startOf('isoweek').add(3, 'days');
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/n20vncp0/

Comment: Time and JavaScript will never get married. Makes me sad. But **moment.js** will save us all.

Comment: This does not work properly as it calculates Thursday of week after next.  What the OP wants is two weeks after next Thursday.

Comment: Using moment, what you would want is
    var GivenDate = moment();  var CalculatedDate = GivenDate.add((4 - GivenDate.day() + 7) % 7 + 14, 'days')

Answer (score 1):

You could add 14 days then add the difference between Thursday (4) and the current day of the week. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwo79jkt/3/).

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 14 + (4 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7);
```

Comment: You calculate dayDif as 4 - date.getDay(), but then you have to check if it is less than 0 add 7, otherwise leave it.  You could accomplish the same by calculating dayDif as (4 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. I have here a function that calculates how many weeks forward you want and then a target day of the week it will find after the specified amount of weeks.

I'm using moment.js.

Check out the JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ravvy/ea1u903k/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dateOfNextTwoThursdays = getDateAfterWeeks(2, 'Thursday');
    $('#dateOfNextTwoThursdays').text(dateOfNextTwoThursdays);

    function getDateAfterWeeks(numberOfWeeks, dayString) {
        if (!numberOfWeeks || numberOfWeeks < 1 || !dayString)
            return null;
        if (dayString != 'Monday' && dayString != 'Tuesday' && dayString != 'Wednesday' && dayString != 'Thursday' && dayString != 'Friday' && dayString != 'Saturday' && dayString != 'Sunday')
            return null;

        var weeksFromNow = moment().add('days', numberOfWeeks * 7);
        var dayOfTheWeek = weeksFromNow.format('dddd');

        if (dayOfTheWeek === dayString)
            return weeksFromNow;
        else {
            while (dayOfTheWeek != dayString) {
                weeksFromNow = weeksFromNow.add('days', 1);
                if (weeksFromNow.format('dddd') === dayString)
                    return weeksFromNow;
                dayOfTheWeek = weeksFromNow.format('dddd');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have an idea of how to do this with out using moment and just bringing in the date from an external source?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just jump to next week then loop through the days (adding one each time) until you land on thursday?

```
function getNextThursday(current){
    if(!current){
        var current = new Date();
    }
    var newday = new Date(current.getTime() + (86400000 * 8)); // next week plus 1 day in ms
    while(newday.getDay() != 4){
        newday = new Date(newday.getTime() + 86400000);
    }
    return newday;
}
var nextThursday = getNextThursday();
```